# Are there any cheap ways to get from Jamaica to Cuba?

Tags: air-travel, budget, cuba, sea-travel, jamaica

I'm looking for a flight from Montego Bay to Santiago de Cuba (preferred) or La Havana, but I can't find anything below 400 euros (my trip is one way, at the end of July).

Are there any cheap airlines, ferries, or cruise lines that serve this route? Is there a way to transit through another Caribbean island to save money?

Comment: It *[looks like](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/is-it-possible-to-travel-to-cuba-by-sea-from-e-g-mexico)* there are no ferries to Cuba at all... (if that turns out to be false, post an answer to my question too!)

Comment: I'll do :) I think that there are cruises that arrive to Cuba, but I don't know if you can take that kind of cruise on one port and leave in the next one, and I'm afraid the price for this will be even higher than for a fly.

Comment: the way your question was written, it looked like you were specifically asking about a specific fare in July. This might be too localized to get an answer. I rephrased your question to make it more general so that it is not closed as "too-localized".

Comment: Any ship that docks in a Cuban bay will be forbidden to dock in any bay of US territory. Maybe this is why it is not easy to get to/from Cuba by ship.

Answer (score 7):

There's one way you may not have considered - although it's quite adventurous.

Websites like [Find A Crew](http://www.findacrew.net/) advertise boats going from A to B all around the world.  They're usually looking for crew.  Some will want experienced crew, while others just want someone to share the journey, and price of fuel and food with, as long as you're happy to help out and learn.

A friend who cycled from London to New Zealand did this from East Timor (?) to Australia, onboard a yacht for a couple of weeks. She had zero sailing experience.