# Travel to Cuba as Dual Citizen (Dutch born-Dutch/US Citizen)

Tags: us-citizens, dual-nationality, cuba, dutch-citizens

This is actually a question a friend of mine had that I couldn't answer directly and really don't know the laws specifically.

If a person already has dual citizenship (specifically American and Dutch) but was born Dutch are they still required to follow travel restrictions to Cuba?

It is unlawful for an American citizen to travel to Cuba since the trade embargo without being granted permission. Most countries do not require a visa up front when traveling as an American citizen and a visa can easily be obtained upon arrival.

Of course there are ways around this rule but without bending or breaking the law of the US.

Would such a travel under a Dutch passport be detrimental to a US citizenship? Or traveling with the US passport even not a native citizen?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Passport not visa. I fixed it.

Comment: FYI, it's [not technically illegal for a US citizen to VISIT Cuba](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/is-it-technically-illegal-for-us-citizens-to-visit-cuba?rq=1)

Comment: It's not? I know that Cuba doesn't mind but I think the US does. I think it was after the Cuban Missile Crisis that the trade embargo stopped. Any travel to Cuba means you are a 'communist'. :) Is this not still in effect?

Comment: As per the linked question, travel isn't illegal, spending money there is.  Of course, the US can't tell that you've spent money there, unless you come back with souvenirs.

Comment: [There's also a detailed Wikipedia page if you're interested](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_embargo_against_Cuba)

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thanks. I did live in Miami for a while and speaking to Cuban-Americans they told me that even they had to get special sanctions to visit. As far as I know there is no direct route from America to Cuba. Spending money to travel to Cuba (a Cuban flight or boatride from Mexico per se still constitutes as spending money to the Cuban government.)

Comment: Indeed, and if you search flights on kayak.com for example, they'll say they can't sell tickets as they're American.  Most I know who have been have had to fly to Mexico, and buy a ticket there

Comment: "Would such a travel under a Dutch passport be detrimental to a US citizenship?" Nothing can be detrimental to U.S. citizenship unless you intend to relinquish U.S. citizenship.

Comment: Illegal from who's perspective? It's not illegal from Cuba's point of view if they allow you into the country. From the US point of view, it is illegal if you spend any money there, however extra-territorial laws are an area of controversy since you would be breaking the law while outside the US' jurisdiction. Either way, I would suggest entering Cuba on your Dutch passport.