# Can US citizens go to Cuba freely and vice versa after the recent diplomatic relation restoration?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, cuba, cuban-citizens

A recent full diplomatic relation restoration between the US and Cuba took place, does that mean that US citizens can go to Cuba freely and vice versa?

Comment: I think you can already go to Cuba as a US citizen freely, as long as you don't spend any money... See [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2684/is-it-technically-illegal-for-us-citizens-to-visit-cuba?rq=1)

Comment: Simply diplomatic relations have been reopened. All other embargoes are being maintained as they presently are, making this essentially a duplicate.

Comment: Conversely, there have been countries without diplomatic relations that made no attempt at preventing travels by their citizens or punishing them when they return.

Comment: While it might still be strictly speaking illegal, it's extremely unlikely that anyone would try to enforce the ban nowadays.

Comment: Wait until the children in Washington get done having their little tantrums about this and the bureaucracy sorts out the details. Cuba will still be there...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**No**, travel is still not completely free.  However, [you are now allowed](http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2014/12/17/fact-sheet-charting-new-course-cuba) to travel to Cuba and spend money there legally under the following 12 categories:

1. family visits
2. official business of the U.S. government, foreign governments, and certain intergovernmental organizations
3. journalistic activity
4. professional research and professional meetings
5. educational activities
6. religious activities
7. public performances, clinics, workshops, athletic and other competitions, and exhibitions
8. support for the Cuban people
9. humanitarian projects
10. activities of private foundations or research or educational institutes
11. exportation, importation, or transmission of information or information materials
12. certain export transactions that may be considered for authorization under existing regulations and guidelines.

Note the absence of plain old "tourism" from this list.  In practice, though, it was already pretty easy to visit Cuba legally under the fig leaf of "people-to-people exchanges", and with these wide new categories, it's about to [get even easier](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/19/travel/how-travel-to-cuba-may-change.html).  (A week of dancing salsa or tasting cigars?  Sounds "educational" to me!)  You will still likely need to go through a travel agent unless sorting out licenses with the Office of Foreign Assets Control sounds like your idea of a good time.

Comment: "8.support for the Cuban people" this can be interpreted in many ways, going there and spending money for tourism is _supporting_ Cuban people.

Comment: I was researching the travel restrictions to Cuba a couple months ago, and I don't notice any differences in this list to what was possible earlier. Do you have any indication of more freedom to travel now than before?

Comment: Previously each trip had to be individually scrutinized and approved by OFAC.  Now you can get a one-off "general license" to travel for these 12 reasons.  http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/dec/17/improved-us-cuba-relations-average-american

Comment: @jpatokal: You don't have to "get" anything at all. The general license applies automatically to all people who qualify; that's why it's "general".

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, US law does not completely forbid travel to Cuba. There are even organized tours.

The main restriction impairing free travel to Cuba is [the embargo](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/pages/cuba.aspx) which prohibits US citizens to conduct business or any monetary transactions with Cuban interests. Since this embargo was established by a series of statutes, the president cannot overturn that without the help of the US Congress and it's unlikely to happen soon.

At the same time, there is a system of [licenses](http://www.treasury.gov/services/Pages/Cuba-Travel-Licenses.aspx) authorizing people to spend money in Cuba to allow travel for limited purposes. Apparently, the current US presidency intends on facilitating that process so even if travel still won't be completely free, it could become easier.

Comment: The licenses link is dead - FYI